# Invalid Binary after Mac App store submission. Probably architecture mismatch

Tags: macos, submission

After i tried to submit my OSX App (directly with Xcode organizer) i get the famous "Invalid Binary" error in iTunes Connect. 
I wonder if the cause of this error would be the architecture defined as default in Xcode 4.2.

Here a screen: 
[image]

In my opinion it's strange to have **i386** for a 64-bit Intel Architectures.

What do you think ? should i try to remove i386 from valid architectures ?

Comment: I found the issue and it's really frustrating... I need to set "Dwarf with dSYM File" as debug information also for "Debug" field... even if i compile as "Release"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only architectures that will actually be built are the ones in BOTH the Architectures and Valid Architectures lists.  So, there is no harm in having i386 in Valid Architectures, and you should look elsewhere for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing your signing settings.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2978664/appcert.png is a Project Info Panel. Double click the Project and make sure the values are correct there. Then in the target if any of the signing options are bold click them and press delete. This way your project settings are used rather than overridden by the target.